# Уподобление механизму — олицетворение?

Tags: тропы

Олицетворение - это уподобление явления либо предмета живому существу.  Тогда можно ли говорить,  что "сердце барахлит" - это олицетворение? Этот пример я нашла на сайте с примерами олицетворения. 
Заранее спасибо за помощь))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, "сердце барахлит" — не олицетворение. Здесь обратный процесс: работа части живого организма — сердца — уподобляется работе мотора. Метафорический перенос в чистом виде. Так что "сердце барахлит" — это метафора.

Answer (score 1):

**Сердце брахлит** (как мотор) ― это **овеществление**, вид метафоры.

Метафора ―  **скрытое сравнение**: заря догорает (как догорает свеча).

В языке используются две основные модели для метафоры: **олицетворение и овеществление.**

**Овеществление**  ― уподобление явлений одушевленного мира неодушевленным, в отличие от **олицетворения,** где неодушевленные предметы наделяются свойствами живых существ.

Пример:

**Облетает моя голова,
Куст волос золотистый вянет** (С. Есенин).